# Drools Errors - org.drools.RuleBase

Tags: java, drools

Hi I am migrating my project from java1.6 to Java1.8 . I have updated my Drools jar from 5.2.1.Final to 6.5.0.Final . Now i am getting error in class -

```
              org.drools.RuleBase
              org.drools.RuleBaseFactory
```

Error in java code -
The import org.drools.RuleBase cannot be resolved--Error in code
The import org.drools.RuleBaseFactory cannot be resolved----Error in code

What changes i have to do to make run in Java1.8

Comment: this is not related to `javascript`. Maybe `java`?

Comment: What errors? Please include the stack trace and the snippet of code that caused it. Drools 5 -> 6 is not a trivial upgrade after all. Also which drools jars specifically are you using? (drools-core?)

Comment: The import org.drools.RuleBase cannot be resolved.    Dependency is already added in pom.xml file Drools core version is "6.5.0.Final" previously it was "5.2.1.Final".

Answer (score 1):

Drools 6 is a major change from Drools 5. There was a massive restructuring and some files ceased to exist. Part of this was due to the change in which algorithms Drools was using (rete vs phreak).

At the end of the day, Drools 6 is *not* a drop-in replacement for Drools 5. You can't just re-version the jars and expect them to work -- some of the jars that were part of Drools 5 don't even exist in Drools 6! For the most part, you can do drop-in replacements within a major version (eg. you can swap 5.x for 5.y. or 6.x for 6.y) up through 7.44 (ish). But major version changes have breaking changes, as do minor versions of 7 greater than 44.

As a concrete example, the class `org.drools.RuleBase` doesn't exist anymore in Drools 6. If you download the drools-core jar, open it up, and explore, you'll see that there are no classes in `org.drools`.

It's been a long time since I used Drools 5, but if `RuleBase` is the class that I think it is, then the Drools 6-specific replacement is `KnowledgeBase`. That class is available in the `knowledge-api` jar, which replaced the `drools-api` jar and serves as a bridge between the deprecated APIs and the new kie apis. In Drools 7, this becomes `KieBase`.

| Version | Class | Jar |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Drools 5 | RuleBase | drools-api |
| Drools 6 | KnowledgeBase | knowledge-api |
| Drools 7 | KieBase | kie-api |

You need to go in and refactor your code to not rely on the deprecated/removed classes, and update your configurations, code, and rules for the new workflows introduced in Drools 6.

Comment: Thanks for update sir. Can i still use old "5.2.1.Final"  for java 8 ? What changes i have to do.

Comment: If you just want to run existing rules, yes you can run drools 5.x as-is if you're using mvel syntax. I maintained a service using Java 8 and Drools 5.0.1 and had no problems though i did have to use no later than Java 5 or 6 syntax in the rules themselves and had to specify mvel dialect (not java).

Comment: Thanks for update Sir. Getting an error "Caused by: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFormatException: null". I have updated ecj jar 4.6.1. and updated my Apache Tomcat to 8.5

Comment: You might want to consider just updating one thing at a time. There's too many moving parts at this point.

Comment: Which drools version will be used in Java11?

Comment: The most recent.

Comment: Hi Sir ..Thanks finally the error resolved .I have removed jdt.eclipse core jar from pom and added ecj .Thanks a lot.